# Calculate normal vector to $2$-face of polytope in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I am trying to work through a divergence theorem application for a function integrated over an $n$-dimensional convex polytope, but I can't seem to figure out how to properly calculate the normal vectors to its surface.

As an example, suppose my polytope lives in $\Bbb R^4$, and is defined as the hypersimplex: $$\left[0,1\right]^4 \cap \left\{ \boldsymbol{x}: \sum x_i = k \right\}$$

If $k \in (2,3)$, this shape is a tetrahedron with the vertices cut off, so now the vertices are replaced with triangular $2$-faces, and original triangular $2$-faces of the tetrahedron are now hexagons. I want to use the divergence theorem to integrate over the boundary (the surface of the hypersimplex), recognizing that this integral will be the sum of integrals over the $2$-faces.

What I am struggling with is how to find the normal unit vector to the $2$-faces in more than $3$ dimensions, and how to ensure that it points "outward" from the convex shape.

Let me define one of the $2$-faces by its vertices so you can answer a specific question. Suppose $k = 2.5$. Then one of the triangular $2$-faces is defined by:

$$(0, 1, 1, 0.5),\ (0, 1, 0.5, 1),\ (0, 0.5, 1, 1)$$

How do I find the normal vector and how do I ensure it points outward?

Comment: If we label the above vertices as $v_1, v_2, v_3$, then one thing I have tried is to just find a vector orthogonal to two edges, e.g.: $$v_2 - v_1 = (0, 0, -0.5, 0.5) $$ $$v_3 - v_1 = (0, -0.5, 0, 0.5)\, .$$ Then $n \cdot (v_2 - v_1) = 0$ and $n \cdot (v_3 - v_1) = 0$.

Comment: $$... \rm{continuing} ...$$ Using this logic, $$ n = (x, 1, 1, 1)\, ,$$ where $x$ is any value in $\mathbb{R}$, and the unit normal is: $$\hat{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 3}} \cdot n \, .$$ Problem is, this gives infinitely many unit normals, and I thought they were supposed to be unique. Is there some principle which says I can just assume/fix $x=0$?

Comment: Interestingly, considering one of the hexagonal 2-faces gets the "same" normal vector. One such face is defined as: $$v_1=(1,0,1,0.5), \, v_2 = (1, 1, 0, 0.5), \, v_3 = (1, 0, 0.5, 1) $$ $$ v_4 = (1, 1, 0.5, 0), \, v_5 = (1, 0.5, 0, 1), \, v_6 = (1, 0.5, 1, 0).$$ This setup gives the same normal vector: $$ n = (x, 1, 1, 1) $$

Comment: I think the intuition is that once we eliminate one dimension, leaving only the necessary three to describe the 2-plane containing the 2-face, then each 2-face is just the hypersimplex in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Thus, its normal vector is naturally (1,1,1) because that is the vector pointing to the outer corner of the unit cube. For this reason, I propose that the unique normal vector be determined according to $x = 0$ in the first triangle example, and $x=1$ in the hexagon example. This should also guarantee that the normal vector points "out", coupled with the logic above. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should be careful about applying the divergence theorem to a 3-dimensional object in $\mathbb{R}^4$.  You will have to make sure to project the vector field onto the hyperplane containing the object and *then* calculate its divergence.  Otherwise the vector field might diverge in the normal direction instead of out of the boundary.

It is also true that a 2-dimensional face has infinitely many normal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$, the same way that an edge has infinitely many normal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

What you want to do is find the vector which is normal to the face, and is *also* parallel to the hyperplane that contains the object.  As you mention in the comments, the vectors along two of the edges are 
$$
w_1 = v_2 - v_1 = (0,0,-0.5,0.5),\qquad w_2=v_3-v-1 = (0,-0.5,0,0.5)
$$
In addition, the normal vector to the whole polytope is
$$
n = (1,1,1,1).
$$
Thus, you want to find a vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$ which is perpendicular to all *three* of these.

There is something like cross product in $\mathbb{R}^4$ for solving this problem.  Given the three vectors, we can compute the "determinant"
$$
\left|\begin{matrix}\textbf{e}_1 & \textbf{e}_2 & \textbf{e}_3 & \textbf{e}_4 \\[3pt] 0 & 0 & -0.5 & 0.5 \\[3pt] 0 & -0.5 & 0 & 0.5 \\[3pt] 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{matrix}\right| \;=\; (-0.75,0.25,0.25,0.25).
$$
(This operation is actually a special case of the [exterior product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_product).)  As you can see, the resulting vector is perpendicular to $w_1$, $w_2$, and $n$, so this is the normal vector you are looking for.

Comment: thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't sure how to extend the cross product to n-dimensions, and the insight about the normal vector to the whole polytope is great. Two thumbs up!

Comment: Upon further reading of your answer, I am not 100% sure what you mean by "project" the vector field onto the hyperplane. Let's say my vector field is very simple: $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$. How would the projection look/be calculated?

Comment: If $v$ is the vector field and $n = (1,1,1,1)$ is the normal vector to the hyperplane, the projection of $v$ onto the hyperplane is $v - \dfrac{v\cdot n}{n \cdot n}n$.

Comment: If you don't mind one more question... projecting the vector field onto the hyperplane really interferes with a simplification I have in my proof, because it forces a form of averaging/interaction between the elements which complicates things. I understand that the problem is things 'accidentally' being zeroed out if the divergence is in the normal direction, but if I have other ways to verify that this does not happen, is it correct to omit the projection step? It seems to me that it would be since the projection essentially just takes out the orthogonal component. Thanks again.

Comment: In particular, I re-tried the problem above with the $3$-cube and a vector field of the form $(xyz,0,0)$. This divergence problem you raise became clear, because everything turns to zero when you go to evaluate the cube's faces. I know that projecting the vector field is an approach that is always correct, but I am asking if there are ways around it which are also correct, if I verify some set of conditions.

Comment: Well, another option is to check that the divergence in the normal direction is equal to zero.  For the normal vector $n=(1,1,1,1)$, the divergence in the normal direction is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_4}\right)(v\cdot n)$.

Comment: This is just the projection of the vector field onto the normal vector, right? It seems that this is non-zero by construction, except in the case where the partials in the divergence cancel (i.e., because some are negative). $$--$$ Rather than continuing to pester you, could you recommend a good resource which explains the need for evaluating a projection of the vector field?

Comment: @user1166202 I'm happy to continue to answer questions, although if you post a new question others would be able to help, too.  I can't recommend a reference for why you have to project the vector field -- it's just based on my understanding of how the divergence theorem works.  The problem is that the divergence theorem only applies to closed $(n-1)$-dimensional manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  If you integrate the divergence of a vector field over the interior region, you get the flux of the vector field through the boundary.

Comment: (continued) The problem with what you're doing is that you're trying to apply the divergence theorem to an $(n-2)$-dimensional manifold inside of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and that *doesn't* work.  However, the "interior region" that you want is really the interior within a certain $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperplane.  So really what's happening is that you're applying the divergence theorem to an $(n-2)$-dimensional submanifold of an $(n-1)$-dimensional manifold inside of $\mathbb{R}^n$, which works because the codimension is one.

Comment: (continued) In general, if $M$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of any dimension, $S$ is a submanifold of $M$ of dimension one that bounds a region, and $v$ is a _tangent_ vector field to $M$, then you can apply the divergence theorem to $S$.  This general version is a standard result in differential geometry.  What this means in your case is that the divergence theorem will only apply if the vector field is _tangent_ to the hyperplane that contains the polytope.  One way of making a tangent vector field is to simply project the vector field you have onto the hyperplane.

Comment: OK. Thank you for such a thorough and detailed response. I will take some time to digest this, as it looks like I have some reading to do!